# How to execute transactions and rollbacks in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sql, graphql, sequelize.js

In the documentation it says:

```
try {

  const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {

    const user = await User.create({
      firstName: 'Abraham',
      lastName: 'Lincoln'
    }, { transaction: t });

    await user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, { transaction: t });

    return user;

  });

  // If the execution reaches this line, the transaction has been committed successfully
  // `result` is whatever was returned from the transaction callback (the `user`, in this case)

} catch (error) {

  // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
  // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

}
```

I thought I would create a wrapper for this and come up with a function like so:

```
export const executor = async (query: Function, db: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      const resp = await query(t);

      return resp;
    });

    // If the execution reaches this line, the transaction has been committed successfully
    // `result` is whatever was returned from the transaction callback (the `user`, in this case)
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
    // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

    // log here

    throw new Error('Internal server error');
  }
};
```

executed like this:

```
const r = executor(param => {
  db.sequelize.query(
    'CALL registerSportUser (:email, :password, :roleId, :firstName, :lastName, :age, :jobTitle, :prefLanguaged, :assigned, :sportId, :tableId, :position, :image, :imageName)',
    {
      replacements: {
        email: args.input.Email,
        password: PasswordHash,
        roleId: args.input.RoleId,
        firstName: args.input.FirstName,
        lastName: args.input.LastName,
        age: new Date(new Date(args.input.Age).toUTCString()),
        jobTitle: args.input.JobTitle,
        prefLanguaged: args.input.PrefLanguaged,
        assigned: false,
        sportId: '11ea859b-e3f3-6ba2-bf71-00ff98e8d5ab',
        tableId: null,
        position: null,
        image: null,
        imageName: null,
      },
    },
    { transaction: param }
  );
}, db);
```

To test this I sent in a value of NULL which gets inserted to a table colum which does not allow nulls. 
This should then rollback all my db changes.

The thing is it doesn't rollback anything...

console shows:

```
Executing (6d1aaebb-5247-4b0d-a9c4-d5b81a6da8db): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (6d1aaebb-5247-4b0d-a9c4-d5b81a6da8db): COMMIT;
Executing (default): CALL registerSportUser('email', '$2b$12$i1mc.tLpG0HjhK0Y9C/gTO1ySwBguOa2Tlr1fFZHUf1IgIKESU3gC', 1, 'firstname', 'lastName', '1988-07-17 02:00:00', 'Jobtitle', 1, false, '11ea859b-e3f3-6ba2-bf71-00ff98e8d5ab', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Column 'TabelId' cannot be null
```

The error is valid since im trying to insert a null value where there should not be a null value BUT why doesn't sequelize rollback all changes?

instead of the error I should be getting:

```
Executing (e5fb0b6b-1340-4f9f-9bf0-f8913ba54751): ROLLBACK;
```

I think my wrapper is the problem but I do not see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to return Promise from **db.sequelize.query**:

```
const r = executor(param => {
  return db.sequelize.query(
    'CALL registerSportUser (:email, :password, :roleId, :firstName, :lastName, :age, :jobTitle, :prefLanguaged, :assigned, :sportId, :tableId, :position, :image, :imageName)',
    {
      replacements: {
        email: args.input.Email,
        password: PasswordHash,
        roleId: args.input.RoleId,
        firstName: args.input.FirstName,
        lastName: args.input.LastName,
        age: new Date(new Date(args.input.Age).toUTCString()),
        jobTitle: args.input.JobTitle,
        prefLanguaged: args.input.PrefLanguaged,
        assigned: false,
        sportId: '11ea859b-e3f3-6ba2-bf71-00ff98e8d5ab',
        tableId: null,
        position: null,
        image: null,
        imageName: null,
      },
    },
    { transaction: param }
  );
}, db);
```

Comment: I could hug you and shoot myself in the foot. Thanks m8!